# arrayOf(1) vs arrayOf<Int>(1) vs intArrayOf(1) in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, integer

- Array is an Integer[] (object) under the hood,
- IntArray is an int[] (primitive)

Why ***arrayOf*** is printing Integer and not using int primitive

[Example](https://pl.kotl.in/-oK2SKCAD)

```
var a = arrayOf(1,2,3)
var b = arrayOf<Int>(4,5,6)
var c = intArrayOf(7,8,9)

println(a) //[Ljava.lang.Integer;@5d099f62
println(b) //[Ljava.lang.Integer;@31cefde0
println(c) //[I@439f5b3d
```

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have primitive type. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html

Comment: @AshutoshOjha, OP is talking about under the hood. It does use primitives in the compiled bytecode. And primitives do have meaning even in Kotlin documentation. For instance, primitive types can not be used with `lateinit` and only primitives and Strings can be used as annotation arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no class hierarchy between IntArray and Array. `arrayOf()` can only return the Array type. If there were an overload of `arrayOf()` that used Ints and returned IntArray, there would be no way to create an `Array<Int>`/ Java `Integer[]`. `intArrayOf()` is completely non-ambiguous.

Comment: If intArrayOf() return an array of primitive int,  hence improving performance, then obviously we should use intArrayOf().  So under what use case will we use arrayOf then

Comment: @NickWills, `arrayOf` is for other classes besides the primitives. If you're asking specifically about `arrayOf<Int>`, I've used Java for about 12 years and never had an occasion where I needed an `Integer[]` or any other boxed primitive array. Usually, if you're using an array instead of a List, you are in some piece of code that really needs to be optimized, so you'll be using primitives. The only example I can think of where you might need that is in a generic function where the generic type may or may not be a primitive type.  But if it's generic, List is a more natural choice.